# How to read all files in a directory using .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

The method below is able to output the contents of a file to the console. How can all the files in a directory be read using .NET Core?

```
try
{   
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\path\\to\\file\\test.txt"))
    {
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Note that tha accepted answer to the question I linked above uses [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-1.0) which is available in .NET Core since .NET Core 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netstandard-2.0) to list all files in a directory.

From there, you can loop through them and read them just like you are reading a single file right now.

---

Additionally, you should consider using a [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netstandard-2.0) with a buffer instead of reading the file. If somebody happens to drop a 20GB text file in that directory, it would lead to a memory intensive process.